# Как подключится к сервису который работает фоном?

Tags: android, android-service, mediaplayer

Суть: я разрабатываю плеер на Android. У меня есть сервис для воспроизведения музыки. Он работает но при нажатии клавиши назад, а потом выбора другого трека он не хочет подключатся к прежнему сервису и создает новый из-за чего треки проигрываются одновременно. Вопрос: как либо подключится к сервису который уже работает, либо уничтожить его?

P.S. При bindService я использую BIND_AUTO_CREATE.

Подключение к сервису

```
serviceConnection=new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                playerServiceBinder=(LPlayerService.LPlayerServiceBinder) service;
                try{
                    mediaController =new MediaControllerCompat(PlayerActivity.this, playerServiceBinder.getMediaSessionToken());
                    mediaController.registerCallback(new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat state) {
                            if (state == null)
                                return;
                            boolean playing = state.getState() == STATE_PLAYING;
                            boolean changing = ((state.getState() == STATE_SKIPPING_TO_NEXT)||(state.getState()==STATE_SKIPPING_TO_PREVIOUS));
                            if (changing){
                                currentTrack.setText(mediaController.getMetadata().getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
                                currentArtist.setText(mediaController.getMetadata().getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
                                songTime.setMax((int)mediaController.getMetadata().getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
                            }
                            if (playing){
                                //startTimer();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (RemoteException e){
                    mediaController=null;
                }

                currentTrack.setText(mediaController.getMetadata().getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
                currentArtist.setText(mediaController.getMetadata().getString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
                songTime.setMax((int)mediaController.getMetadata().getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                playerServiceBinder = null;
                mediaController = null;
            }
        };
        bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Сервис

```
public class LPlayerService extends Service {

    private static final String GET_POSITION = "GET_POSITION" ;
    private static final String GET_TRACK_INFO = "GET_TRACK_INFO";
    final MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int listType;
    private long listId;
    private long trackId;
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID=404;
    Track currTrack;
    MusicRepository musicRepository;
    Timer progressTimer=new Timer();
    Timer trackInfoTimer=new Timer();
    private int repeatMode=0;

    final PlaybackStateCompat.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                        | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS);

    MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent);
//        trackId=intent.getLongExtra("trackId",-1);
//        listId=intent.getLongExtra("idList",-1);
//        listType=intent.getIntExtra("typeList", -1);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "LPlayerService");
        mediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
        Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent (this, PlayerActivity.class);
        mediaSession.setSessionActivity(PendingIntent.getActivities(appContext,0, new Intent[] {activityIntent},0));
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaSession.release();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        if (!mediaSession.isActive()){
            mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this,"LPlayerService");
        }
        mediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS
                        | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
        mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);
        Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent (this, PlayerActivity.class);
        mediaSession.setSessionActivity(PendingIntent.getActivities(appContext,0, new Intent[] {activityIntent},0));
        if (trackId!=intent.getLongExtra("trackId",-1)) {
            trackId = intent.getLongExtra("trackId", -1);
            listId = intent.getLongExtra("idList", -1);
            listType = intent.getIntExtra("typeList", -1);
            musicRepository = new MusicRepository(this, listType, listId, trackId);
            currTrack = musicRepository.getCurrentTrack();
            MediaMetadataCompat metadata = metadataBuilder
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, currTrack.getTrackName())
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, currTrack.getArtistName())
                    .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, currTrack.getArtistName())
                    .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, currTrack.getTrackDuration())
                    .build();
//                  .putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ART,
//                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), track.getBitmapResId()));
            mediaSession.setMetadata(metadata);
            Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null, getApplicationContext(), MediaButtonReceiver.class);
            mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0));
            mediaSessionCallback.onPlay();
        }
        return new LPlayerServiceBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        progressTimer.cancel();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Привели бы пример кода что-ли

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно код из onBind вынести и возвращать ссылку на Binder, а не создавать новый

В моем сервисе:

```
inner class BluetoothServiceBinder : Binder() {
    internal val service: BluetoothService
        get() = this@BluetoothService
}

private val binder = BluetoothServiceBinder()


override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {

    bound++

    state = ServiceState.BOUND

    return binder
}
```

Comment: Т.е. у меня должна в сервисе быть пересенная в которой я буду хранить binder и его надо будет передавать в OnBind?
И прощу прощения, но что вы подразумеваете под вынести код из onBind?

Comment: Код который отвечает за воспроизведение вынесите в другой метод который будете вызывать для начала воспроизведения. В случае "прибинденого" сервиса, особого смысла использовать интены нет, у вас ссылка есть на сервис, по ней можно манипулировать им без проблем, play, pause, stop, etc

Comment: Да, получается типа Sigleton для сервиса [доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=ru)